# if and counifs looping through 2500 rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

after debugging the code error bold line is highlighted yellow . Run time error'91'.I new to VBA so need help on how to write these formulae on single command button and get the results  in columns P,Q,R. The formulae should loop through all 2500 rows?
The formulae are

```
IF(E2="",0,2)
IF(F2="",0,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,F2))
(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,E2))-1
```

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
   **lastRow = sh.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row**
   sh.Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(E2="""",0,2)"
   sh.Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(F2="""",0,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,F2))"
   sh.Range("R2:R" & lastRow).Formula = "=(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,E2))-1"

End Sub

I want the formula to work on click of button
The image shows the error 


How to solve it?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vue2U.jpg
```

Comment: So, each such a formula should be written in that three columns? First in PP, next in Q:Q and so on? Are all the columns in discussion having the same number of rows, equal with the number of rows in A:A?

Comment: First formulae is to be applied in P second in Q and third in column R. Yes number of rows are same of all columns

Comment: And my answer did not answer your question?

Comment: Did you test my answer code? Please refresh the page when try using it...

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that all five (including F:F, E:E) columns in discussion have the same number of rows, try, please this code. No need of any loop...

```
Sub FormulaOnThreeRanges()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   sh.Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(E2="""",0,2)"
   sh.Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(F2="""",0,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,F2))"
   sh.Range("R2:R" & lastRow).Formula = "=(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,E2))-1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Friendly hint: think you've overlooked assigning the code fragment `sh.Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` to `lastRow` :-)

Comment: @T.M.: I would not say like that... Since his formulas are referencing columns E:E and F:F, one of them should be good enough. What range do you think would be more appropriate?

Comment: didn't check the correct column, but syntax: suppose you get a compilation error for a stand-alone line like `sh.Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` :-;

Comment: @T.M.: Ups... Only now I understood what you mean. I missed `lastRow` to be calculated there. Thanks! Code looks so simple, that I did not test it and I was sure it cannot be wrong... Corrected the code.

Comment: Please help Runtime Error '91' Object Variable or with object variable not set

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
   lastRow = sh.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   sh.Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(E2="""",0,2)"
   sh.Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(F2="""",0,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,F2))"
   sh.Range("R2:R" & lastRow).Formula = "=(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,E2))-1"

End Sub

Comment: @any: Please, refresh the page and test the code again. It should work now.

Comment: same error is occuring                                                                                               Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
   lastRow = sh.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   sh.Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(E2="""",0,2)"
   sh.Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(F2="""",0,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,F2))"
   sh.Range("R2:R" & lastRow).Formula = "=(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,E2))-1"

Comment: You forgot to refresh the page! `Set sh = ActiveSheet` is missing from your code...

Comment: I have pasted the link to image please have look at spreadsheet[1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nv7s.png

want to apply the three formula on column P and second formulae on Q and third on R on click of single button.

Comment: @any: I would understand that from what you requested, but please refresh **THIS** web page and copy the correct code again. It keeps the old code if you do not do that... You must see the line `Set sh = ActiveSheet` in the code (the third one...)!

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked..does writing formulae in VBA will work fast as compared to writing it in excel?

Comment: how to write these three formulae in VBA                                                                           First formulae==IF($P2>0,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$F:$F,$E2,$D:$D,"<13"),0) Second formula =IF($D3<13,(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A3,$E:$E,$E3,$D:$D,"<13"))-1,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A3,$E:$E,$E3,$D:$D,"<13")) third formula =IF(AND($D2>=13,$D2<=60),(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$E:$E,$E2,$D:$D,">=13",$D:$D,"<=60"))-1,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$E:$E,$E2,$D:$D,">=13",$D:$D,"<=60"))

Comment: So, did you succeed to use my above code? Does it return what you asked in your question? I will help you with this new request if you confirm that the code answer your initial question...

Comment: Yes the code provided by you worked.I got the desired results. Thanks..But I think it is taking the same time whether I write formula in excel or through VBA. I have a lot of data with many excel formulae. Is dere any way I can make the processing fast?

Comment: If I apply filter processing is still slow. Actually I was writing VBA to decrease the processing time but I think it is same

Comment: Did you mentoon something about filtering? If this is your problem the formula result must be calculated in VBA, not only write the formula like you asked. Please define what formula to be reproduced. I am driving now and I do not want to loose time doing something to be changed...

Comment: No filtering in the code is not required. I was just mentioning about the performance of excel after putting in the formula for calculating 6000 rows. It takes few minutes even to apply filters to columns.

Comment: This is not what I suggested! If the VBA way shuold increase filterring speed, you should mention that and VBA should CALCULATE the formula result, instead of formula writting... that is why I asked what formulas to be calculate by VBA...